# How to load index from for loop inside widget to use it in if condition

Tags: apostrophe, apostrophe-cms, nunjucks

I have widget load pieces and I set for loop to load single item inside this widget and I want inside for loop to set index for each element to take advantage from it to make if condition, How I can do that?

here is my for loop inside widget:
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}

and I tried to set index like this but it didn't work:
{% set index = data.piece.__dotPath | replace(".", "-") %}

Comment: Are you talking about the index of the for loop (starts at 0, goes up by one each time the loop continues), or are you just wanting to set a variable called index? If I understand what you're wanting, you should change data.piece.__dotPath to piece.__dotPath. data.piece doesn't mean anything in this context - the variable 'piece' in your for loop will contain each piece in your list of pieces.

Comment: I am talking about the index of the for loop (starts at 0, goes up by one each time the loop continues) I tried :
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
{% set index = loop.index %}
<script>console.log(`{{ loop.index }}`)</script>
and it prints on console the numbers
but when I make if statment like:
  {% if loop.index == 0 %}
    <h1>Hi</h1>
    {% endif %}
    it didnt work
also I tried to use groupby but it did'nt work also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nunjucks's built-in `loop` object, you can conditionally check what index your loop is at and choose to do something special like

```
{% for piece in data.widget._pieces %}
    {% if loop.index ===  1 %}
        ... something special
    {% else %}
        ... something normal
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```